# Game Development or Game Developers?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

This site seems to have an identity problem. The site name in the logo is *Game Development*. But the page title is *Game Developers*, and that name is used in the [FAQ](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) as well. I know the site's name might change later, but it still looks weird now.

Can we have all references of "Game Developers" changed to "Game Development"?

Comment: Game Development has been decided as the correct name and has been adjusted.

Comment: @Geoff Dalgas: That's great. Not to be too picky, but it still says Game Developers Meta in the meta's page title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let's look at the original Area 51 proposal:

> http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2825/game-development
>
> #### Game Development
>
> Proposed Q&A site for professional and independent game developers who would like to discuss the various aspects of video game development and design.

Which is more correct?

Comment: Development is probably more correct.  The site is about the process more so than the people.

Comment: That's because the proposal form asks you to define who the site is for. The Photography proposal says it's for professional photographers but the site's name is still Photography.